# How to solve ODE $\frac{d^2}{dt^2} f(x,t)-4\pi |x|^2 f(x,t)=0, f(x,0)=g(x)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R)$ and $g\in C^2(\mathbb R^n)$ satisfies the ODE
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} f(x,t)-4\pi |x|^2 f(x,t)=0, f(x,0)=g(x)$$

> My Question is: How to solve  the above ODE?

Comment: plz show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that x is not function of t, this is a ordinary ODE

$${\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}f \left( t \right) -4\,\pi\,
 \left(  \left| x \right|  \right) ^{2}f \left( t \right) =0$$

characteristic equation:
$${r}^{2}-4\,\pi\, \left(  \left| x \right|  \right) ^{2}=0$$
$     \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad $ 
$ r=2 \left| x\right|  \sqrt{\pi }$ and $r=-2 \left| x\right|  \sqrt{\pi }$

$$f \left( t \right) ={\it C1}\,{{\rm e}^{-2\, \left| x \right| \sqrt 
{\pi}t}}+{\it C2}\,{{\rm e}^{2\, \left| x \right| \sqrt {\pi}t}}
$$
but we have partial differential equation then gerneral solution is;

$$f \left( x,t \right) ={\it C1} \left( x \right) {{\rm e}^{-2\,
 \left| x \right| \sqrt {\pi}t}}+{\it C2} \left( x \right) {{\rm e}^
{2\, \left| x \right| \sqrt {\pi}t}}
\qquad\qquad (1)$$

With the condition:$f \left( x,0 \right) =g \left( x \right) $ putting in $(1)$ we have:

$$g(x)=f(x,0)=\text{C1}(x) \exp (0)+{\it C2} \left( x
 \right) \exp (0)$$

$$g \left( x \right) ={\it C1} \left( x \right) +{\it C2} \left( x
 \right)
$$

$${\it C1} \left( x \right) =g \left( x \right) -{\it C2} \left( x
 \right) 
$$
and paste to $(1)$

$$f \left( x,t \right) = \left( g \left( x \right) -{\it C2} \left( x
 \right)  \right) {{\rm e}^{-2\, \left| x \right| \sqrt {\pi}t}}+{\it 
C2} \left( x \right) {{\rm e}^{2\, \left| x \right| \sqrt {\pi}t}}
$$